# Can one extend a Hermitian bundle from a compact manifold with boundary to its Riemannian double?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, sobolev-spaces

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with boundary, and let $E \to M$ be a Hermitian vector bundle, endowed with a compatible connection. Let $\tilde M$ be a Riemannian double of $M$.

> Does $E$ extend to a Hermitian bundle (with a compatible connection) $\tilde E$ over $\tilde M$?

The motivation is the following: theorem 8.7 in Eric Amar's ["Sobolev embeddings with weights in complete Riemannian manifolds"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08613) proves a version of the Sobolev embedding theorem for sections in Hermitian bundles, corollary 8.8 is the same result for compact manifolds *without* boundary, and finally theorem 8.9 proves Sobolev's theorem for Hermitian bundles over compact manifolds *with* boundary, **under the assumption that the bundles extend to the Riemannian double** (in order to use corollary 8.8). I wonder whether this assumption is always verified, and is thus redundant.